# Does my forgot password works correctly or am I missing something?

Tags: php, mysql

When a user registers, there is a random value `md5(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM))` into `verified` column until he verifies his account. When this happen (by email), `verified` goes empty.

When a user wants to receive again his email verification, types his email in a textbox and there are 4 possible situations :

1. Non valid email -> please-correct-your-email.php
2. Valid email -> this-email-is-not-found.php
3. Valid email + found in DB + verified -> is-already-verified.php
4. Valid email + found in DB + not verified yet -> still-not-verified.php

My question is if my logic and construction are correct and also if I forgot something. It works correctly though.

```
if ($_POST["email"]) {

require_once('config.php');

    $errflag = false;

$send2email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);

    if (!filter_var($send2email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errflag = true;
    }    

    if($errflag) {
        header("location: please-correct-your-email.php");
        exit();
    } 

    $qry = "SELECT verified FROM members WHERE email='$send2email'";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    if($result) {
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)  {
            header("location: this-email-is-not-found.php");
            exit();
        }
        elseif ( (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) && ($member['verified']) ) {
            header("location: still-not-verified.php");
            exit();
        }
    else {
            header("location: is-already-verified.php");
            exit();
    }
            }

                    } //this is for if post email
```

Comment: Looks fine, a bit convuluted, but don't see any glaring mistakes.

Comment: Move `$member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` to be inside of `if ($result) {}`

Comment: I just don't get it why people voted to close it.

Comment: Please note that `a = 'a'` can be case sensitive, whereas `a LIKE 'a'` does the same, but is never case sensitive.

Comment: swap `filter_var` and `mysql_real_escape_string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd change verified to a boolean field. It means

```
verified BOOLEAN
------------------
1
0
```

instead of "when he's not verified, field is filled, when he's verified, field is blank". It's little bit confusing.

I'd move

```
    $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

after

```
if ($result){
```

I'd add confirm code, because it makes no sense to do email verification without secured code (verification code)

Comment: Thanks. `verified` holds `md5(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM))` and goes empty when the user is verified. It may not be the best solution but it works until now...

Comment: but verification is based only on email

Comment: @Nikolai, if you are using the `verified` field to actually check the validation code that you send to the user, then you should call it `validationcode`, not `verified`. Anyway IMO the query `select count(*) FROM members WHERE email = '$send2email' AND validationcode IS NOT NULL`, makes your intend clearer _minor difference I know._

Comment: @Johan So I guess it works ok, except of some minor changes. I agree with your verified to validationcode, is a problem because English is not my language.

Comment: @Nikolai I agree with the boolean part.

Comment: @Mario ok I agree with all, I am changing the structure to a column named `validationcode` and `verified`. `validationcode` will hold the code and `verified` BOOLEAN 0 or 1. I guess this will make the structure easier to understand even though there will be an additional column. Is this the best approach ?

Comment: @Nikolai, It is much better to ask the less and to smaller data columns in MySQL (if you get what I mean).
Making a boolean column for that will have not-at-all-ever-noticeable impact in your table size and the queries will be ultra-fast even more if you index it.